# tkinter default button in a widget

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

this seemed easy...

I wrote a dialog widget where I put some entries, buttons etc - among which a button I'd like to activate by mouse click, but also by pressing return.
I read time ago that it was just necessary to set its *default* option, but I think that it changed in recent versions.

Do you know how it is possible to set it ?

thanks!

Comment: The default config option for a button is just a visual, you don't need to set it, but if you're going to make it act like the default you should.  (And bind <Return> to invoke it as Steven Rumbalski indicated.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bind a callback to the `'<Return>'` event to the window (often called `root` in Tkinter) or to the containing frame.  Have the callback accept an event parameter (which you can ignore) and have it `invoke()` your button's callback.

```
root.bind('<Return>', (lambda e, b=b: b.invoke())) # b is your button
```

Comment: it would have been cleaner as an option to the selected button, but I can live with this: it works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
def myaction():
    print('Your action in action')

def myquit():
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
label = Label(root, text='Label Text').pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
label.bind('<Return>', myaction)
label.bind('<Key-Escape>', myquit)
ok = Button(label, text='My Action', command=myaction).pack(side=LEFT)
quit_but = Button(label, text='QUIT', command=myquit).pack(side=RIGHT)
root.mainloop()
```

1. You must declare your functions first.
2. Notice that the 'My Action' button and the Return key both call `myaction` and 'QUIT', and the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key both call `myquit`.

Hope that helps.